# SCSS Font Name Turns into Hexidecimal

Tags: css, sass, nuxt.js, sass-loader

Hello I am using NuxtJS with the Sass loader and upon a `nuxt generate` to create static page files, the CSS get's compiled incorrectly.

```
      "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
      "nuxt": "^2.4.0",
      "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
```

When testing with just `npm run dev` on my local machine, everything works fine.

here is my source css styles:

```css
$serif_font: 'Crimson Text', serif;

label {
    font-family: $serif_font;
    font-style: italic;
    color : $dark_gray;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
}
```

This is what appears in my browser in the inspector:

It turns the word 'Crimson' into a hexidecimal value.

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix this? Is this a bug with `nuxt.js` or `sass-loader` ???

The only thing I found online was this article from 2017 but it has no solution:
https://www.jotform.com/answers/1269781-Advanced-Designer-Choosing-Crimson-Text-as-the-font-family-results-in-broken-CSS

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. What version of `sass-loader` and/or `node-sass` are you using?

Comment: I updated my original post with the versions

Comment: @Zac Did you happen to find a solve for this? I've been running into the same issue.

Comment: @jiminy hey jiminy, I unfortunately did not. I do not remember exactly what I did to get around it, but I did something or it just fixed itself. Everything in production went fine tho

Comment: @Zac Thanks for getting back to me. We ended up swapping the fonts to one without a colour in the font name. This is still a confounding issue though.